# Saving Dask DataFrame with image column to HDF5

Tags: image, dataframe, dask, hdf5

I am trying to load images of varying sizes into a Dask DataFrame column and save the dataframe to HDF5 file format.

Here's the standard approach:

```
import glob

import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread


dir = '/Users/petioptrv/Downloads/mask'
filenames = glob.glob(dir + '/*.png')[:5]

df = pd.DataFrame({"paths": filenames})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf['images'] = ddf['paths'].apply(imread, meta=('images', np.uint8))
ddf.to_hdf('test.h5', '/data')
```

I get the following error message:

```
...
  File "/Users/petioptrv/miniconda3/envs/dask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2214, in set_atom_string
    item=item, type=inferred_type
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [images] because
its data contents are [mixed] object dtype
```

Essentially, PyTables detects that the column has an `object` dtype and checks if it's of type `str`. It's not, so it throws an exception.

I can probably hack it by opening the images into byte-arrays and converting those to strings, but that is far from the ideal scenario.

Comment: When you say "Spark", do you mean "Dask"?

Comment: Yes, Dask DataFrame. Thank you for pointing that out! Fixed the question and description.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `data_columns` as suggested in [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8284#issuecomment-55784169) issue.

```
ddf.to_hdf('test.h5', '/data', format = 'table', data_columns = ['images'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried it but no luck